# Why is the square root calculation slower for larger numbers?

Tags: java

This is a Java code to ask for a number then printing its square root without using Math.sqrt() method:

```
import java.util.Random;
import java.io.*;
public class Square {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        final double TOL = 0.5E-15;
        InputStreamReader reader = new InputStreamReader(System.in);
        BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(reader);
        System.out.print("Enter a number to get the aquare of it: ");
        double n = new Double(input.readLine()).doubleValue();
        Random random = new Random();
        double x = random.nextDouble();
        do {
            x = (x+n/x)/2;
        } while(Math.abs(x*x-n)>TOL*2*x);
        System.out.println("sqrt(" + n + ") = " + x);
    }
 }
```

Please run this in you computer and test it for several numbers.
for numbers below 30.1, it runs and calculates the square root quickly. But when you enter 30.2 or larger numbers, no square root is calculated(at least with feasible waitings)!
Any interesting explanation for this behavior?!

Comment: It becomes an infinite loop for certain inputs.

Comment: A while loop doing exactly what it's supposed to do isn't very "strange". Perhaps using the debugger or putting a print statement in that loop would shed some light on the mystery.

Comment: An accuracy of `0.5E-15` is a bit too much to ask with this method. Unless you need the squareroot to ensure the Mars rover lands safely on the surface.

Comment: Your characterization of the output is incorrect.  Just try some larger numbers such as 100 or 225, and not only exact integral squares.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you have there is the so-called [Babylonian method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Methods_of_computing_square_roots#Babylonian_method) for computing the square root of a number. However, I think that your stop condition should be only a scalar (for example `TOL`) and not `TOL*2*x`.

Answer (score 4):

change the do-while to:

```
do {
    x = (x+n/x)/2;
    System.out.println(x);
    System.out.println(x*x);
} while(Math.abs(x*x-n)>TOL*2*x);
```

this gives repeatly (for input 30.2):

```
5.495452665613634
30.199999999999992
```

as you can see is the square of 5.495452665613634 30.199999999999992, this has as result that the condition `Math.abs(x*x-n)>TOL*2*x` is always fullfilled (the difference is `7.105427357601002E-15`. while the condition is `> 5.4954526656136345E-15`, which is true)

in otherwords, you forgot that a computerprogram has some limitations for storing values, or your TOL isn't high enough

Answer (score 2):

Well the entire code is built on the premise that at some point you will get the correct value for x. What you get from the Random object will affect the time as will the size of the number you choose.

It's not really an efficient way of calculating sqrt.

Answer (score 0):

Why random? a coded double judiciously choosed avoid calcul like `x*x`

In your code you can add `*2` to the TOL definition and remove `*2` from loop

Good programming remove all unnecessary things

Answer (score 0):

The "problem" is that `double` has a limited precision: The larger the number represented, the larger the inaccuracy - that is the larger the smallest change must be to store a different `double`.

Once your attempted answer exceeds a certain numerical size, `double` can not resolve the number finely enough to achieve the accuracy defined by `TOL`.